# Let $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$ and $\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha - \gamma) = k$, where $0 < k < 1$. Determine $\sin(\beta)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Let $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$ and  $\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha - \gamma) = k$, where $0 < k < 1$. Determine $\sin(\beta)$.**

I think that: Since $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$, so $\sin(\gamma) = \sin(\alpha + \beta) = k$.
Note that
$$
\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) +\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) \text{and} \sin(\alpha -\gamma) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)$$
Then, since $\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha - \gamma)$, we obtain
$$
\sin(\alpha)(\cos(\beta) - \cos(\gamma)) - \cos(\alpha)(\sin(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)) = 0.
$$
I can't achieve anything yet.

Comment: You know that $\sin\gamma=\sin(\alpha-\gamma)$.

Comment: @SaiMehta Ok. And now?

Comment: Then $\gamma=2k\pi+\alpha-\gamma$ or $\gamma=(2k+1)\pi-\alpha+\gamma$. Using this you can find a relationship between $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ which can help find $\sin\beta$ in terms of $\sin\gamma$.

Comment: But, we have $\alpha + \beta = 2k\pi + (\alpha - \gamma)$.

Comment: @SaiMehta I can't :(

Comment: Use $\beta=\pi-\alpha-\gamma$. If $\gamma=2k\pi+\alpha-\gamma$ then $\alpha=2\gamma-2k\pi$, so $\beta=(2k+1)\pi-3\gamma$. If $\gamma=(2k+1)\pi-\alpha+\gamma$ then $\alpha=(2k+1)\pi$, so $\beta=-\gamma-2k\pi$. If $\beta=(2k+1)\pi-3\gamma$ then $\sin\beta=\sin((2k+1)\pi-3\gamma)=\sin(3\gamma)=3k-4k^3$. If $\beta=-\gamma-2k\pi$ then $\sin\beta=\sin(-\gamma-2k\pi)=-\sin\gamma=-k$.

Comment: @SaiMehta Thank you so much